# Jquery code not working for scrolling animation on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my Query code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       $('.js--scroll-to-discount').click(function () {
             $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('js--section-discount-opt').offset().top}, 1000);
       });

});
```

This is the HTML code of the button to be clicked:

```
<a class="btn btn-full js--scroll-to-discount" href="#">I'm ready Dallas</a>
```

This is the section the animation should take you within the page:

```
<section class="discount-city js--section-discount-opt">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error in your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       $('.js--scroll-to-discount').click(function () {
             $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('js--section-discount-opt').offset().top}, 1000);
       });

});
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       $('.js--scroll-to-discount').click(function () {
             $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-discount-opt').offset().top}, 1000);
       });

});
```